# Last Element of Array different values

Tags: c, arrays, file, while-loop

I have an array with fifteen elements and at each while-loop pass the last value is changed or at least it's clearly wrong. Sometimes it is incremented, sometimes it just jumps to another memory address value probably under the control of the program. First I zeroed all values. Code:

```
int w16 = 0;
int len[15];
for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i){     //zero the array
    len[i] = 0;
}
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    printf("while: %d \n", len[15]);
    if(isspace(c)){
        word = 0;
        if (0 < letters && letters < 16){
            len[letters] = len[letters] + 1;
            letters = 0;
        } else if(letters > 15){
            ++w16;
            letters = 0;
        }
    }else if (word == 0) {
        word = 1;
        ++letters;
        ++nw;
    } else if (word == 1) {
        ++letters;
    }
}
```

Some output of the printf command. I can't see where it gets changed in the above code and why only the last one, all others are fine:

```
while: 111 
while: 110 
while: 101 
while: 32 
while: 49 
while: 50 
while: 51 
while: 52 
while: 53 
while: 54 
while: 55 
while: 56 
while: 57 
while: 115 

Before fclose: -1
```

Any ideas about what might be wrong in here? Everything else is fine apart from this nasty bug. I recently moved to C from Java and I as well may be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int len[15];
```

This declares an array of 15 elements. They are indexed from `0` to `14`.

Accessing an array out of bounds is Undefined Behavior. Make sure you never access `len[15]` or beyond. Or, if you need 16 elements, make it `int len[16]`.

Another way, if you need to access elem `1-15` you can declare an array of 16 elements and just ignore the first one (index `0`). Although this might seam the easiest way if you are not accustomed to zero indexed arrays, I won't recommend it as nearly all programming languages use zero indexed arrays, and sooner or later you will have to wrap your head around this. See [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)

Comment: You got it from the first time +1

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a value that has not been assigned, i.e. beyond you array parameter of index 0-14 or length = 15. So you will get a 'junk' value that's taken randomly (or from the first available space) from non allocated memory.
here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i){

for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i){
```

and here:

```
if (0 < letters && letters < 16){

if (0 < letters && letters < 15){
```

although I'm not 100% clear if letters is the length or the index.

I assume index as you're using `len[letters]` In which case you need to account for letters ==0.

Also, I suggest using the name len as an array name is a terribly confusing choice.

Comment: the problem was my declaration, I intended to declare a 16-element array, where I don`t use the 0-element